# javascript context issue - parameters undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this code:

```
targetMu: function(programmeCode, muId) {

//Parameter values are fine here

  targetMuController.targetMuView.on("targetMu:afterRender", function(programmeCode, muId) {       
        this.renderCustomWidgets(muId, programmeCode);
  });
}
```

When `this.renderCustomWidgets(muId, programmeCode)` gets fired, `programmeCode` & `muId` is undefined, why?

And how can I fix this?

Comment: does the event `targetMu:afterRender` provide these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove parameters from anonymous function:

```
targetMu: function(programmeCode, muId) {
    targetMuController.targetMuView.on("targetMu:afterRender", function() {       
        this.renderCustomWidgets(muId, programmeCode);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
, function(programmeCode, muId) {
```

You just declared new parameters in the callback function with the same names.

Inside the callback, these names refer to the inner parameters – whatever was passed to the callback.

Comment: Makes sense, I was pulling my hairs out.